# Django view param is not unquote with FastCGI

Tags: django, unicode, nginx, fastcgi

I have Django site in Nginx+FastCGI, and if there is special char in URL the view param parsed by Django is not unquoted.

Example:

```
# python manage.py runfcgi port=8099 --settings=settings
browser url: http://127.0.0.1/Contact/%E6%9C%B1/
Django urlpattern: url(r'^(?i)Contact/(?P<q>.*)/$', 'qsearch'),
```

param 'q' catched by qsearch function is **u'%E6%9C%B1'**. BUT it is expected to be **u'\u6731'** as unquoted.

The same program works fine to get u'\u6731' when using runserver for debug.
So I have to use workaround method：

```
q = unicode(urllib.unquote(str(q)), 'u8')
```

Nginx conf:

```
location / {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8099;
    include /home/fastcgi_django.conf;
}
```

fastcgi_django.conf:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name; 
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string; 
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method; 
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type; 
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri; 
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri; 
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root; 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1; 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr; 
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port; 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr; 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port; 
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
```

Dont know the problem is from Nginx or Django or FastCGI interface. Hope someone can help.

Charlie